# Encourage moving questions to other SE sites

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, scope, low-quality-posts, migration

I've just seen this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838119/wondering-about-future-programming-career

It's clearly out of topic for StackOverflow, but still I can't see any constructive value in the mere downvoting.

I'd like to propose an idea: should we create a policy that encourages people (and mods) to move (or tell to the asker to!) the question to another StackExchange property? I've seen this done many times, but not as often as I would like to.

The main perk would be to help populate the other SE sites, and it would help to keep SO clean also.

A proper badge and some discounts on the downvote loss of reputation may be created to encourage the behavior.

What do you think?

**Edit:** curiously, the asker asked the same thing This is the outcome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838119/wondering-about-future-programming-career#comment55441593_33838119 and the outcome is this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838119/wondering-about-future-programming-career#comment55441627_33838149

As for the "question is crap part in the comments" I guess it may be useful to bear with the asker and ask them to improve it.

Comment: This kind of question is not on topic anywhere on the SE network. An attempt was made once to create a site where all the off-topic but somehow programming related questions could go but [that failed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) and today, that site has a super-sharp scope just like SO. That's the biggest reason why migrating questions is so tightly controlled and restricted.

Comment: Wouldn't be it home on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ? You may question the quality of the question, but the scope is pretty much the same.

Comment: As-is, the question is crap. And the golden rule of migration is "**Don't migrate crap.**" Could the OP have a question which would be on-topic on programmers if he rethought it all, did lots more research, and started anew? Maybe, but that isn't it.

Comment: If a user can't be bothered to do the minimum amount of research to see if their question is on-topic where they are posting it, I don't think their question can have any value.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: I wonder what bozos upvoted that link-only-answer he got. Oh well, the question will probably be deleted manually before the roomba could reap it anyway.

Comment: Why would you feel sorry for me?

Comment: You are free to help the OP to improve his question, by prompting him or editing. But unless the end-result is a bit more likely to be on-topic here, or at least migratable, refining that question is just a waste. Sending the OP to [help/on-topic] and optionally mentioning a site **in comments** which would welcome that question (as-is, unless you are sure you can convince the OP to ask better there) is also helpful.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Actually, suggesting alternative SE sites to an OP whose question is in a terrible state of disarray is discouraged. It just gives them somewhere else to try peddling their filth, _before_ applying some effort to tart it up a bit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, if one cannot convince the OP to improve his next one sufficiently, mentioning a better isn't (much) better than migrating crap directly. Otherwise, also making him aware that there's a better site for that topic isn't that bad...

Comment: @TZHX what are you referring to? I didn't say anything like that, or if I said it, it has been removed. Wish you all a good night.

Comment: The revision-history will stay though.

Comment: @Deduplicator good stuff for archaeologists http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/310756/4

Comment: @tacone: You did, and you know you did. I don't understand why you would pretend not to have done, unless you have a _really_ poor memory. I removed it because it had no relevance to anything ever at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you for removing it then, altering my posting intent.

Comment: You do not have an ironclad right to write nonsense in your posts.

Comment: It's not nonsense, but just the feeling I get when somebody calls "idiots" the people (at the time just one!) who dare to upvote a post. I think you misbehaved.

Comment: There was more than one idiot, so idiots is the correct word to use.

Comment: related: [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)

Answer (score 3):

> I can't see any constructive value in the mere downvoting.

The constructive value is in discouraging any more such open-ended, unresearched, discussion-style "questions" from manifesting here or, indeed, on any other Stack Exchange site… and, more importantly, in marking the question as bad for other people (both directly, and through the magic algorithms that keep various Stack Exchange robots doing useful things).

Downvoting, closing and deleting is the correct course of action.

> As for the "question is crap part in the comments" I guess it may be useful to bear with the asker and ask them to improve it.

If this doesn't encourage the OP to improve their question, then I don't know what will.