# Can we improve the off-topic reason for asking for recommendation for tools, software, etc.?

Tags: discussion

Currently the off-topic message says:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

But, sometimes, the OP really wants to ask for a recommendation of software, but does not have a specific issue in mind. Can we add one more short sentence to explain that if they need a recommendation, they can go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com , and also offer an option to to vote for migrating there?

Comment: Let's not offer a migration path. Unless you're familiar with the SR.SE guidelines it will become a catch-all for recs in general

Comment: Software Recs do not want us to offer a migration path. Shouldn't we respect their wishes?

Comment: @RobertLongson, what is the  reason why Software Recs do not want StackOverflow to offer a migration path? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: The suggestion is specific to SoftwareRec. Referred as original closed suggestion https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310756/encourage-moving-questions-to-other-se-sites is generic and has different proposal. The more appropriate  duplicate candidate is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370255/why-does-the-recommend-and-find-a-book-or-tool-close-explanation-not-ment/

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/760/should-we-migrate-questions-from-other-se-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes they do, yes.

Even so, such questions are not good questions for Software Recommendations. They *still* need to identify a specific problem and hammer out specific requirements. "What's the best editor?" is every bit as off-topic on SoftwareRecs as it is on SO.

So if the close reason applies, we'd not exactly be doing them a service by recommending SoftwareRecs.

However... If they *have* identified a specific problem and set of requirements... And the question *still* isn't suitable for Stack Overflow for some reason... Then you're more'n welcome to post a comment pointing them at SoftwareRecs.